# Why do malloc and calloc have different signatures?

Tags: c, language-design

`malloc` and `calloc` have these signatures:

```
void* malloc( size_t size );
void* calloc( size_t num, size_t size );
```

They do basically the same thing. Both allocate a chunk of memory of the specified size and return a pointer to that chunk. The difference is that `calloc` initializes the whole memory to zeros. Actually, `calloc` could be implemented kind of like this:

```
void* calloc( size_t num, size_t size ) {
    void * ptr = malloc(num*size);
    if(!ptr) return NULL;
    return memset(ptr,0,num*size);
}
```

(I know that there are [reasons to not implement it like this](https://locklessinc.com/articles/calloc/), but that's not the topic.)

Since they are so similar, what is the reason for their different signatures? When you call `malloc` you specify the number of bytes you want and when you're calling `calloc` you specify a block size and the number of blocks. I don't prefer one over the other, but it bothers me that they are different.

Imagine that you have written a piece of code with some `malloc`s, and then you realize that all of these allocations need to be zeroed. If they had the same signature it would mean that you only have to change the "m" to a "c".

Was there ever a reason for this design choice, or was it just a coincidence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C that was standardized had experienced one and a half decades of organic growth. Not everything has to make perfect sense. Indeed, many standardized functions do not make much sense, such as the inherently unsafe `gets()` function.

The allocations of `calloc(n, sizeof(T))` and `malloc(n * sizeof(T))` may allocate different amounts of memory depending on alignment restrictions of the system. This is not an issue on the x86 architecture, but may apply on other architectures.

Comment: What does alignment have to do with it? [Only wrap-around seems potentially relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699574/can-calloc-allocate-more-than-size-max-in-total).

Comment: @Deduplicator I was operating under the mistaken assumption that the array allocated by calloc() would not be an object, and this difference would be relevant on platforms where objects must be aligned by their size, e.g. a 300-byte object to a 512-byte boundary. Alignment padding would change memory consumption. I am now convinced that the allocated memory *is* an object, so there cannot be a difference. (For example, glibc's malloc does not take alignment into account except when requested via valloc(), but glibc is not very portable. These differences don't matter on AMD64 architectures.)

Answer (score 2):

If size_t is 32 bits, and pointers are 64 but, then they are not equivalent at all if size * nitems doesn’t fit in 32 bits.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is genius language-lawyering or false. The largest size of an object is size_t. Your observation applies iff the memory allocated by malloc() is not an object (but just a memory region that may hold objects). The size of pointers is not immediately relevant as pointers may be much larger than total addressable memory (e.g. some architectures use weird function pointers, so normal pointers are made larger so that all pointers have the same size in C).

Comment: I always thought that anything the memory allocation functions could return counted as an "object", but this does ever so slightly shake me with the interesting doubt that maybe the memory region pointed to by `calloc` is not required to be considered a single "object" - if `malloc` and `realloc` always had to return an "object" but `calloc` was free of that requirement, then "legally" `calloc` would be allowed to allocate memory larger than `size_t` bytes (`char`s). But as far as I know the meaning of "object" in the C standard is meant to include the memory regions allocated by `calloc` too.

Comment: Just checked, and I think this is it! From the [last C89 standard draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html), emphasis added: [4.10.3.1 The calloc function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.10.3.1) says "The calloc function allocates space for **an array of** `nmemb` **objects**, **each** of whose size is `size`.", while [40.10.3.3 The malloc function] says "The malloc function allocates space for **an object** whose size is specified by size and whose value is indeterminate. " ! And the `realloc` definition *also* talks about a singular object !!! So this was deliberate.

Comment: @mtraceur Thank you for hunting down the correct place in the standard. This disproves my theories. Arrays are objects, so calloc() is not special.

Comment: @amon I'm not so sure - that's how I wanted to interpret it initially (because I **want** `calloc` to be limited to allocation sizes that fit in `size_t`), but unless I missed it, the C89 final draft never explicitly says that `size_t` can hold the size of any "object", and the way we get that idea is because it says that `size_t` must hold all values that `sizeof` can give, and `sizeof` must be able to give the size of any type that it can actually operate on. But while `sizeof` can get the size of array **types**, it cannot ever get the size of dynamically allocated regions of memory.

Comment: And while it is possible that all uses of the word "array" were meant to be implicitly understood to be "objects", it is not clear to me from the parts of C89 that I remember reading that the usage of the word "array" in the `calloc` definition was actually intended as such, because the standard goes out of its way to say "array object" instead of just "array" in many other places. Newer standards might be more rigorous and explicit in a way that pins this ambiguity down, but this question was about the historical reasoning so I have been focusing on the C89 standard.